# Compress programs

Tags: code-golf, compression

Write a program/script that decompresses and passes any compressed data appended at the end of the binary/file as standard input to a program specified as arguments.

```
$ gzip --to-stdout input >> your_solution
$ your_solution program args...
```

should have the same effects as:

```
$ program args... < input
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**zsh: (20 chars)**

*Edit:* because zsh doesn't re-parse arguments like bash, I can lose the `"`s and it will still work with spaces in args

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
tail -n+3 $0|zcat|$@
```

**Bash (<strike>25</strike> 24 chars not including shebang line)**

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -n+3 "$0"|zcat|"$@"
```

Comment: Could `-n +3` be changed to `-n+3`?

Comment: @idealmachine yes, yes it could... (tho i had to test that :D)

Comment: Also just realized that if i used zsh, I would be able to lose the `"`s and still have it work with spaces...

Answer (score 2):

**C (251 chars)**

Way too long to win, but I wanted to do one in a compiled language to make things interesting. (It turned out to be quite straightforward actually).

It's probably very compiler-dependent (I used GCC 4.4.3 with the default settings on 32-bit Linux)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define q(x)FILE*x=x##open(
#define w strcpy(o+b
o,s=7462;char b[99];main(int i,char**a){q(f)*a,"r");while(--s)fgetc(f);
for(o=0;++s<i;o++[b]=32)w,a[s]),o+=strlen(a[s]);w,"|zcat");q(p)b,"w");
for(;~(i=fgetc(f));fputc(i,p));fclose(p);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash (OP solution)

This is an example I came up with:

```
cat $0 | awk 'NR > 1' | zcat | $* ; exit
```

Comment: this fails if there are spaces in any args

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will leave it as such, your solution is better.